# prevent macvim automatic line break

Tags: settings, macvim

I have MacVim installed, even know I have ":set wrap" on, it automatically creates a line break whenever it hits the right side of the window.

Is there another setting I should be looking it?

This doesn't seem to be an issue in Windows.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved - add the following lines to your vim_rc:

```
set wrapmargin=0
set textwidth=0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:set formatoptions-=t
```

Add the above line to your `.vimrc` file without the `:` to make the setting permanent.

- http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#fo-table.
- http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Word_wrap_without_line_breaks